Why does the TeamCity Inspection step not always apply the naming rules according to a consistent pattern?
We use TeamCity Professional 2024.03 (build 156166) on-premises.
The code inspection step does not apply the naming rules described in CleanCode.sln.dotsettings according to a consistent scheme.
We have two rules specified but it seems that only one of them is getting applied.
Example:
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/Naming/CSharpNaming/PredefinedNamingRules/=PrivateInstanceFields/@EntryIndexedValue"><Policy Inspect="True" Prefix="m_" Suffix="Id" Style="AaBb_AaBb"><ExtraRule Prefix="m_" Suffix="" Style="AaBb_AaBb" /></Policy></s:String>
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/Naming/CSharpNaming/PredefinedNamingRules/=PrivateStaticFields/@EntryIndexedValue"><Policy Inspect="True" Prefix="s_" Suffix="Id" Style="AaBb_AaBb"><ExtraRule Prefix="s_" Suffix="" Style="AaBb_AaBb" /></Policy></s:String>

With that Code:
[TestFixture]
public class InspectionTest
{
   private int m_Id = 15;
   private static int s_Id = 30;
   
   [Test]
   public void Then_it_should()
   {
       Assert.AreEqual(15, m_Id);
       Assert.AreEqual(30, s_Id);
   }
}

We are getting the following Inspection-Errors:
Name 'm_Id' does not match rule 'Instance fields (private)'. Suggested name is 'm_'.
Name 's_Id' does not match rule 'Static fields (private)'. Suggested name is 's_'.

From our understanding, m_Id should be a valid name. After changing the field names to m_Idx and s_Idx, the inspection error disappears. If you then revert again, there will no longer be an inspection error.
Please contact us for more information. How can this behavior be explained?

What ReSharper CLT version do you use on TeamCity? For the latest 2024.1.3 version please try add the following strings to .dotSettings file
 <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/Naming/CSharpNaming/UserRules/=4a98fdf6_002D7d98_002D4f5a_002Dafeb_002Dea44ad98c70c/@EntryIndexedValue">&lt;Policy&gt;&lt;Descriptor Staticness="Instance" AccessRightKinds="Private" Description="Instance fields (private)"&gt;&lt;ElementKinds&gt;&lt;Kind Name="FIELD" /&gt;&lt;Kind Name="READONLY_FIELD" /&gt;&lt;/ElementKinds&gt;&lt;/Descriptor&gt;&lt;Policy Inspect="True" Prefix="m_" Suffix="" Style="AaBb" /&gt;&lt;/Policy&gt;</s:String>
        <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/Naming/CSharpNaming/UserRules/=f9fce829_002De6f4_002D4cb2_002D80f1_002D5497c44f51df/@EntryIndexedValue">&lt;Policy&gt;&lt;Descriptor Staticness="Static" AccessRightKinds="Private" Description="Static fields (private)"&gt;&lt;ElementKinds&gt;&lt;Kind Name="FIELD" /&gt;&lt;/ElementKinds&gt;&lt;/Descriptor&gt;&lt;Policy Inspect="True" Prefix="s_" Suffix="" Style="AaBb" /&gt;&lt;/Policy&gt;</s:String>
    

